# Jquery counters & variables and square brackets

Tags: jquery

A form with this hidden field is loaded

```
<input type = "hidden" class = "counter" value="6">
```

I use Jquery to do this

```
var counter = $(".counter:last").val()
```

then a click event adds a row with this text field

```
.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'drugName["+counter+"]')
```

this returns

```
 <input size="40" type="text" name="drugName["+counter+"]">
```

Where am I going wrong. I tried multiple variations.

Any help/references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'drugName['+counter+']')
```

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is just part of a string in line:

```
.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'drugName["+counter+"]')
```

It should have been:

```
.append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'drugName[' + counter + ']')
```

Comment: Edited to remove double quotes.